# rgb2hed not giving the same answer when applied to a full or part matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image

I have an image in rgb format that is loaded into a 3D numpy array. I would like to convert this image from RGB to HED using the `rgb2hed` function from `skimage.color`.

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.color import rgb2hed
np.random.seed(42)
img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (10, 10, 3))
rgb2hed(img)
```

This works fine and is the result I would like to end up with. The problem is that this image is very big and so I can't fit two copies of the matrix in memory at one time. What I have done to get round this is split the matrix into smaller chunks and applied it to each chunk in turn.

```
img = img.astype(float)
x_split_inds = np.linspace(0, img.shape[0], num_tiles + 1, dtype=int)
x_start = x_split_inds[:-1]
x_end = x_split_inds[2:]
for start, end in zip(x_start, x_end):
    img[start:end, :, :] = rgb2hed(img[start:end, :, :])
```

However, the two matrices calculated by these methods are not the same (the latter method is wrong). What is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Difference is one is called with uint8 data, while the other is called with float data. Which completely changes the result. You probably are using 0.19.3 version of sckit-image, which has a broken `rgb2hed`. None of the cases (from uint8 for from float) is correct.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this space. Do you know if I could install an older version of scikit image that will have a working rgb2hed? And if I do this will I still have a problem with the uint8 and float?